# Custom template for woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, themes

How can I customize the layout of the WooCommerce single product page template in my WordPress theme?

I have tried to create new template file in child theme, but that couldn't help it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.